# Prove PQ = PR, with P midpoint of arc CB and PQ $\perp$ OC, PR $\perp$ OB

Tags: geometry

In the figure, P is the midpoint of the arc CB of the circle with the centre O. If PQ is perpendicular to OC; PR is perpendicular to OB, prove that PQ = PR.

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MtsN.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\angle$QOP =  $\angle$ROP, due to the midpoint P on the arc.

Along with the shared side OP, the right triangles QOP and ROP are congruent, hence QP = PR.